# R get column name in loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

This sounds like it should be easy but I cannot find how to do this in R. How to loop trough all columns of a dataframe and add the column name and a other value (label column value) to a new dataframe? The dataframe `df` in below code is a existing dataframe and only contains numeric columns and one `label` feature (only 0 or 1 values). In below code the `colnames(i)` part is not working because it expects a list. How to print the column name of `i` in the loop? The `biserial.cor(i, df$label)` function in the for loop needs two parameters. Where the first one needs to be numeric vector and the second one should be a boolean vector (only 0 or 1). So the expected result in the `bis.cor.table` should be as below:

```
colname  corrWithLabel
col1     0.45
col2     0.12
col3     0.8
```

```
#Create new dataframe
    bis.cor.table = data.frame(colname = character(),
                               corrWithLabel = numeric())

    #Loop trough df and add values to dataframe bis.cor.table
    for(i in = df) {
      new.df = data.frame(colnames(i), biserial.cor(i, df$label))
      names(de) = c("colname", "corrWithLabel")

      bis.cor.table =  r.bind(bis.cor.table, new.df)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and an expected result

Comment: what is `df`, could you give `dput(df)`?

Comment: @user63230 df is a dataframe that contains only numeric columns. Except for one binary column named label (0 or 1 value). The dataframe contains more then 100 columns so giving dput(df) here would not be very confenient.

Comment: While it can be very natural in other programming languages, you rarely loop over things in R since it is a vectorized language. You should rephrase your question on "How can I do XXX with R?". There will be plenty of answers then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are quite a few typos in your code, but I think I understand the logic.
By fixing them, here is what I have :

```
df = data.frame(col1 = runif(10),
                col2 = runif(10),
                col3 = runif(10),
                label = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE))

#Create new dataframe
bis.cor.table = data.frame(colname = character(),
                           corrWithLabel = numeric())


#Loop trough df and add values to dataframe bis.cor.table
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  new.df = data.frame(colnames(df)[i], biserial.cor(df[i], df$label))
  names(new.df) = c("colname", "corrWithLabel")

  bis.cor.table =  rbind(bis.cor.table, new.df)
}
```

Not sure it's the best way to do it though, and I haven't been able to test if the results are accurate.